# problema com page complete em ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Eu tenho um codigo que está funcionando relativamente bem mas tem um pequeno problema que nao sei como resolver...

Em um pagina eu tenho varios combos que ao clicar lançam pedidos ajax e vao completar outros combos e em simultaneo restringem uma tabela com os novos valores. Parece mto complicado mas ate não é e está a funcionar bem com excepção de quando eu lanço um pedido ajax tem a famosa imagem a informar que o pedido está em curso e que desaparece quando os dados sao retornados.

Ora comigo isso não está correndo mto bem , pois quando faço o pedido que implica actualização do combo e da tabela (este pedido é o que retorna mais dados pois é quando ainda tem muita informação por filtrar) ele actualiza bem o combo mas tem uma diferencça da actualização da tabela que chega a ser de varios segundos, desaparece a imagem e 4 ou 5 segundos depois os dados da tabela actualizam...

Vou deixar a parte do codigo onde coloco os pedidos e as funções ajax, para tentar entender se será daqui que vem o problema... se necessitarem de outros codigos para entender o resto do processo é só pedir.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 /*first call----------*/
 $(document).ready(function () {  
 $(".drop").change(function () {        // ao clicar no combo mostra a div onde estao as          
  imagens de processamento enquanto a resposta não é page complete
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
 $("#wait").css("display", "block");
 });
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
 $("#wait").css("display", "none");    // ao obter resposta de complete volta a esconder    
 a div que tem as imagens de processamento
 });
    var id = $(this).val();
    var dataString = empresa + id;    // establece agumas variaveis a passar no pedido  
  ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "empresa.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (html) {

            $("#tab2").html(html);     // retorna o valor do processado na pagina do 
   pedido e substitui a div com esse valor
            $("#tab3").text(" ");      // insere texto em branco para "limpar" as outras 
    divs
            $("#tab4").text(" ");

            /*second call*/
            $.ajax({            // em simultaneo com o 1º pedido lança este 
    pedido a uma pagina diferente para retornar em uma div diferente 
                type: "POST",
                url: "lista.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function (html) { 
                    $("#nomes").css("display", "block");
                    $("#nomes").html(html);

                }
            });
        }
      });
```

Comment: **Crie um contador global de quantos ajax estão ocorrendo.** Ao realizar um ajax, vc incrementa essa variável e no "complete:" voce decrementa e chama a funcao para mostrar o loading. Na funcao de loading verifica que o contador é maior que 0 e nao esconde enquanto o contador nao for 0.

Comment: mas não deveria a função   $(document).ajaxComplete(function () controlar todos os pedidos ajax visto que é uma global(se nao estou dizendo nenhuma asneira...)entao assim posso repetir o codigo a cada pedido ajax que fizer...mas isso tambem nao ajuda, pois me parece que a pagina recebe o codigo de complete, embora a tabela ainda nao esteja totalmente gerada...

Comment: Sim, mas se houver algum gap entre um ajax completar e outro começar essa ajaxComplete será chamada antes da hora. Em todo caso deixe um break point nesta função e veja qual é o momento inapropriado que ela está sendo chamada.

Comment: alguma chance de me ajudar com esse codigo para o breackpoint ? sou muito verdinho nessas coisas?Obrigado

Comment: user, linha de ação complementar à sugerida pelo Roger, eu estimularia você a criar um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) emulando o problema. Você pode emular falsas respostas ajax (com *delay*) utilizando a API de [echo](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html). Para ter um senso do *delay* dos seus serviços atuais use a aba *Network* do Chrome (`Ctrl+Shift+I`) ou similar. Leia mais sobre o debuger do Chrome em https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Bem eu não tenho muitos conhecimentos mas deu para entender um pouco o que estava causando o problema com a dica do chrome(network), pois a 1ª chamada era bastante rápida e realmente tinha mesmo que gerar o complete..., entao fica a solução que resultou em pleno no meu caso ...

retirei as globais ajax complete....

```
     $(".drop").change(function () {
     $("#wait").css("display", "block");  // fica fixo aqui o aparecimento da div
```

e coloquei no ultimo pedido o esconder da div...

```
   $("#nomes").css("display", "block");
    $("#nomes").html(html);
                $("#wait").css("display", "none");
```

e pronto sempre que está a pedir algo a imagem está no ecra e assim que os dados sao retornados volta a esconder , pode não ser muito perfeito , a nivel de linguagem de programação , mas resolveu meu problema perfeitamente!